# How can I extract jsonString from this method that depends on a task?

Tags: swift

```
    var temp = ""
    let appid = "**************"

    struct WeatherData {
        
    // Object with latitude and longitude to process requests
    // from OpenWeatherMap.
    var lat, lon: Float
    init(latitude: Float, longitude: Float) {
        lat = latitude
        lon = longitude
    }

    func retrieve() {
        var jsonString = ""
        // Send request to OpenWeatherMap.
        let requestAddress =  "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(lat)&lon=\(lon)&appid=\(appid)"
        // Assign the URL to retrieve JSON, with ! dangerous
        // operation.
        let url = URL(string: requestAddress)!
        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
        let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            let data = data
            jsonString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!
            print(jsonString)
        }
        
        task.resume()
        
        
    }
}


var bangkok = WeatherData(latitude: 13.736717, longitude: 100.523186)
print(bangkok.retrieve())
print("Program running...")
print(temp)
RunLoop.main.run()
```

The issue I'm having is only **print()** works but not a return statement or an assignment to a global variable which is what I need. I ultimately want to parse this jsonString into a working dictionary except that I can't get it out of the function at the moment.

I'm depending on a webpage that has only *text* as body content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It common to return the result via a completion block:

```
enum AppError : String, Error
{
    case unknownFailure
    case requestFailed
    ...
}

func retrieve(completion: @escaping (Result<Data, AppError>) -> Void)
{
    ...

    let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: url)
    { (data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode,
               statusCode != 200
            {
                completion(.failure(.requestFailed))
            }
            else if let data = data
            {
                completion(.success(data))
            }
            else if let error = error
            {
                completion(.failure(.requestFailed))
            }
            else
            {
                completion(.failure(.unknownFailure))
            }
        }
    }
    
    task.resume()
}
```

You need to choose where to convert the received `Data` to JSON and ultimately to some `Codable` `struct`.

You must also decide on how to handle errors and what detail you want to pass to a caller.  In the above example I hide the details of `dataTask()` `error`s and put them all under app-custom `.requestFailed`.